# Did John Nash Jr. write equations on the windows of a Princeton library?

Tags: united-states, psychology, economics, movies

I know that the pen ceremony at the end of the film, *A Beautiful Mind*, to announce that he had won the Nobel Prize in economics was completely fiction.

What about the scenes in the movie that showed him writing mathematics on the windows of one of Princeton's libraries?  Is this factual?

Comment: Sorry we don't allow claims uniquely based on movie scenes. It's fiction, it's not claimed to be an exact reproduction of reality.